# Dump Documentation [NelmioApiDocBundle] v3.0

Tags: symfony, documentation, symfony4, openapi, nelmioapidocbundle

I'm using the NelmioApiDocBundle (v3.0) in my symfony 4 project and I want to dump the documentation of my Api project.

I see it's possible to do with older version of NelmioApiDocBundle with this command :

```
php bin/console api:swagger:dump destination_folder
```

but I got this error :
    There are no commands defined in the "api:swagger" namespace

I don't know if it's still posible to dump the documentation with the new version of NelmioApiDocBundle

Comment: In which format do you to export it ? It seem that the version 3 don't have this feature yet. There is the [command previous code](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/2.x/Command/SwaggerDumpCommand.php) if you really need it, you can implement it yourself.

Comment: This feature was added in version 4 (see https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle/blob/master/Command/DumpCommand.php) as `nelmio:apidoc:dump` but it is not available in 3.x yet.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing NelmioApiDocBundle makes me almost sure you are using FOSRestBundle, if you are I'd change to api-platform, you make ask why? First of all you get the API doc by default on route /api (no matter what format etc you always get full doc) second of all the bundle is easy to configure even if you need some custom funcionality like access to property per operation and even depending on role more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60340261/how-to-set-normalization-groups-based-on-users-role-and-request-method) I've tried FOSRestBundle on Symfony 5.0 but it couldnt provide with the funcionality and configuration I desired and then I found out about the API platform. In case I missed your desired answer let me know in the comment and I'll provide the answer as good as I can

Comment: Using FOSRestBundle is definitely not a requirement to using NelmioApiDocBundle. ApiPlatform is not for everyone in my opinion, for instance it makes it quite difficult to customize the API output, so I think implementng things manually still has its avantages. In any case this question is not related to ApiPlatform at all ;)